# Non stretching ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scroll view inside a liner layout, here is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Other widgets go here -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- Scroll view content -->
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want ScrolView's height was dependent to its content - wrap it, however if this height makes the whole layout height more that screen size it should be fixed to fit screen's height.
How can achive it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? If the content is larger than your screen, you do not want the ScrollView to be scrollable?

Comment: can u put your xml file here,,,solvek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the scrollview to fill the entire screen even if the data isn't enough to do so then try this instead

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Other widgets go here -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <!-- Scroll view content -->
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

add this as attribute to the scrollview

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: Uhm, adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the scrollview is already shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5181051/1842065) posted ~4 years ago.